# How to restore the toolbar in the left side of ubuntu unity?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, toolbar

I used the following command on the terminal of ubuntu by accident and now I can't see the toolbar in the left side of ubuntu unity anymore, any one can help ?

**setsid unity**

Now I cannot even see when I swtich between applications by using alt+tab (alt+tab works but I cannot see it). So how to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. 
put **unity --reset-icons** on the terminal
and r**eboot**
can solve this problem.